# jQuery SlideToggle Method but not based on height of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

use the jQuery slideToggle method to show some content after I click on a title:

```js
$(".main-section .main-section-title").click(function() {
  $(this)
    .parent()
    .next(".content")
    .slideToggle(500, "linear");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main-section'>
  <div class='main-section-title'>
    Title1
  </div>
</div>
<div class='content t1' style='height:30px;background-color:green;'>
</div>

<div class='main-section'>
  <div class='main-section-title'>
    Title2
  </div>
</div>
<div class='content' style='height:100px;background-color:blue;'>
</div>
```

It's a one-page website so there are multiple of these titles and content elements on the page. Because the jQuery slideToggle methods animation speed is based on the height of the element, the animations all have a different slideUp and slide down the speed. Is there a solution to use the jQuery slide-method but where the speed is constant regardless of the height of the element. Something like sliding down 100px in 1000ms?

Comment: Add the relevant HTML as well so we can help properly. At the moment I am not sure if anyone would have any idea what’s really going with code above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check below code. I have added explanation in comment.

```js
$(".main-section .main-section-title").click(function() {
  let contentDiv = $(this).parent().next('.content');
  // define constant time based on your requirement
  // if you want to slide 100px per second then use (1000/100)
  // 1000(millisecond) is constant that is for one second.
  // get total slide time = div height * 1000 / slidePixelPerSecond
  // below I have used 1000/10 so it will slide 10px per second.
  let time = contentDiv.outerHeight() * 1000 / 10;
  contentDiv.slideToggle(time, 'linear');
});
```

```css
.t1 {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main-section'>
  <div class='main-section-title'>
    Title1
  </div>
</div>
<div class='content t1' style='background-color:green;'>
</div>

<div class='main-section'>
  <div class='main-section-title'>
    Title2
  </div>
</div>
<div class='content' style='height:100px;background-color:blue;'>
</div>
```